# how to add functions to a class with an implements

Tags: java, android

How do I use my setter in the below code?

```
public class SignalRunnable implements Runnable {

    private final int x;
    private short[] s;

    public SignalRunnable(int _x) {
        this.x = _x;
    }

    public void setS(short[] _s) {
        this.s = _s;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // DO STUFF here
    }
}
```

I've tried the below to use my class, but am getting a cannot resolve method error.

```
    // Create the runnable/task to repeat.
    Runnable runnable = new SignalRunnable(x);

    // Cannot resolve method error here.
    runnable.setS(s);
```

Comment: that's because you declare it as a Runnable, instead of as a SignalRunnable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable is of type `Runnable`:

```
Runnable runnable = ...
```

And `Runnable` has no method called `setS`.  That's a custom method on your `SignalRunnable` class.  Make your variable of that type:

```
SignalRunnable runnable = new SignalRunnable(x);
runnable.setS(s);
```

You can still add your `SignalRunnable` instance to collections of `Runnable`, pass it to methods expecting a `Runnable`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Clearly explained how to resolve my issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should remember one, quite important design principle mandated by the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle):

API (that is, accessible, often referred to as `public`), available on a reference variable, is determined and projected by the type of the variable, and not by the type of the actual object, variable stores the reference to. Type of the variable is whatever it is declared with, not what it refers to.

In case of:

```java
SuperType obj = new SubType();
```

`obj` will only let you access members declared in `SuperType` (including whatever `SuperType` inherits implicitly or explicitly from its supertype(s)).